# How to set value to a range called from a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a value to a cell but it's showing an error "Range not found".

Following is the code:

```
function setpush(pushes) {
 var sheet2 = SreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange(pushes),
    pushcell = sheet2.getCell(1,1).setValue("PUSH_SENT");
}
```

Actually, I'm trying to create a custom function for Google Spreadsheet. The variable push is declared at the very starting of the code.

Following is the full code, in case, if the error is due to the code structure.

```
// Function that you need to call with valid parameters to check when to notify the user and then if all conditions are met then notify the user
function notify(boolean1, pushes, title, body, url) {
  if(boolean1 == "Yes" && pushes != "PUSH_SENT") { //// prevent sending duplicate pushes
    sendNotification(pushes, title, body, url); 
    return "Fired";
  } else {
     return 'Not Fired';
  }
}

/////

// Function that sends notification to an email id
function sendNotification(pushes, title, body, url) {
//  Check if edit was made in sendNotificationBoolean, If it was changed then proceed
  //  Get Range of data that we need to proceed from active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("basic").getRange('B19'),
//      Get email id from range
      email = sheet.getCell(1, 1).getValue();

      //  Run a loop and perform appropriate checks to make sure email id is valid and sendNotification boolean is true/yes
  if(email && email.indexOf("@") != -1) {

/* Variable that stores Payload
 * email: User email
 * type: Type of notification, It can be Note, Link or File. Note suits this. 
 * body: Body of notification, Any message that you want to send goes here.
 * title: Title of notification
 */

    var notificationData = {
      "email": email,
      "type": "link",
      "body": body,
      "title": title,
      "url": url
    }

// Important data that has to be sent with every request
// Change access token to change the user from whom notification'll be sent
    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers': {
        'access-token': 'o.13zCbw5nkk9f3VubcJBhZPG2NpCZjTat'
      },
      'payload': JSON.stringify(notificationData)      
    };
//    Perform a POST request along with options and payload
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes", options);
    {setpush(pushes)}
    }
}

///// Set a value for column N

function setpush(pushes) {
 var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange(pushes),
    pushcell = sheet2.getCell(1,1).setValue("PUSH_SENT");
}
```

Comment: One obvious item is that you are setting the variable "sheet" to a range in your sendNotification function, then later trying to get a range from a range. Change the line to `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("basic");` by removing `.getRange('B19'),` and putting a semicolon on the end.  If you need to use the data in cell B19., you can next add this line: `var cellB19_range = sheet.getRange('B19');` or `var cellB19_value = sheet.getRange('B19').getValue();` (untested) You can then use `var email = sheet.getCell(1, 1).getValue();` (I only added var to the front)

Comment: I'm not trying to get value from any particular cell. You mistook the code I'm referring to. I'm talking about the function "setpush(pushes)" which is at the end the script. Scroll down a bit. in the bigger code in the thread.

Comment: I'm not trying to get value from any particular cell. You mistook the code I'm referring to. I'm talking about the function setpush(pushes) which is at the end the script. Scroll down a bit. in the bigger code in the thread. However, I had also made changes according to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Similar comments:  `var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Alerts").getRange(pushes),` Needs to end with ;, not a comma.  You are getting a Range already, which uses notation as passed to the function.  So if the function is passed "B19" you are getting a range of B19.  If passed B19:F19, you are getting the range of including those cells.  So in your line `pushcell = sheet2.getCell(1,1).setValue("PUSH_SENT");` you are trying to get a range of a range, which there is no such thing.

Comment: Also, setting a Custom Function is suggesting you are placing `=setpush("B19")` or `=setpush(B19)` in a cell.  The first will pass the range B19, the second assumes a range nbotation is in cell B19 and uses that.  Either way, I don't think you intended that this is actually a Custom Spreadsheet Function, correct?  This is the type of thing you would not use a cell formula to do.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be giving the `getRange()` method a single string as the sole parameter in your `setpush()` function.  The only way this single parameter is acceptable is if the string is in A1 notation, eg. `getRange('Alerts!A1:D4')` and/or `getRange('D4')`.

To troubleshoot, you could `Logger.log` the value of `pushes` each time you call `setpush()`, or run a simple test function, like so:

```
function test() {
  setpush('A1');
  setpush('not A1');
}
```

Where the expected outcome would be a `PUSH_SENT` in cell A1 on your spreadsheet, followed by the **Range not found** error that you're familiar with.

See the [documentation for getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) for more information.